# Handling survey data with numerical outliers

Tags: r, statistics

I'm currently working with some survey data, where people are ask questions like "how old are you?" and "how long have you been on your currently workplace?", and they answers by typing their age, workplace experience in a numerical answer.

Furthermore there is a question in which people are asked, whether or not they receive a monthly bonus. If the answer "yes", they get access to the next question regarding, how big that monthly bonus is, which people who answered "no" skipped.

The data was collected on the internet, where people received an invitation by mail.

There is just one little problem. The people that created the survey forgot to put an "rule" on the question asking people about their age and the bonus, which have resulted in answers like "1950" eg. to the question regarding their age.

Some people have answered values to the question about the monthly bonus, which must be interpreted as outliers or extreme values.

It's a fairly large data set, so overall I necessarily don't care that much about the individual response. But as a subset of the data has to be sent to other department in the firm, I would like to apply a transparent method, which also leaves me with most usable answers.

My question is, how should one go about handle these answers?

My currently approach is:
- If the answer to the age is something like "1950", I subtract that answer from 2016 to get their age. Furthermore If they answer something, which is totally nonsense like "197", I just put their answers as missing. 
- If the answer to question about the size of the bonus is greater than the 95% percentile, I code their answer as missing. This gives me a nice normal distribution. The only problem is, that I end up with 10 observation or so fewer answers to that question, than to the question about the got an bonus.

How would you handle these answers? Keeping in mind that, I have to apply an transparent method, which leaves me with most observations.

I know there is no "right" and "wrong", but I would really like to hear other peoples experience and advice.

Comment: I don't know how the rest of your dataset looks like, but you could try to impute the data, using for example the [MICE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) package. I have quite good experience with it. Furthermore, I don't know what your next steps would be, but quite some algorithms are able to handle NAs, without throwing away the whole observation. Can you elaborate a bit further on these topics?

Comment: It is not so much the programming side of the question. It's more the "ethical" of how one should go about handling these "wrong" answers from the respondents. I'm just looking for the "best practice", other people experience and so on, and to get a debate about a good strategy for handling these answers and about the potential criticisms that may arise. I know that there isn't a solid answer here. Does it make sense?